# Rails get sum of field grouped by using includes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following models

```
class Application
  has_one :referral
  has_one :detail
end

class Referral
 belongs_to :application
 belongs_to :status
end

class Status
  has_many :referrals
end

class Detail
  belongs_to :application
end
```

Now I want to get the sum of the price in detail table for each referral grouped by their status

I wrote this code but i keep getting an error regarding missing FROM clause for table details..

```
ref_application_count = Referral.joins(:status).includes(:status).eager_load(application: :detail).group("statuses.assignment_status").select("statuses.assignment_status, count(applications.detail.purchase_price)")
```

I know this has to do with the fact that my details table doesnt have any relationship with referral table but is there still a way i can optimize this code to get it to work?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to the following:

```
Referral
  .joins(:status, application: :detail)
  .group('statuses.assignment_status')
  .select('statuses.assignment_status, sum(details.purchase_price), count(*)')
```

Comment: There is also a rails method called [sum](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/sum) for calculating the sum of given attribute.

Comment: if i want to get back the count of each referral by status and also the sum how do i do it? @AndresEhrenpreis

Comment: Like this: `Referral.joins(:status).group('statuses.assignment_status').count`  or you don't want status name: `Referral.group(:status_id).count`

Comment: So i will have to two queries? one for sum by status and one for the count by status? can the 2 queries be combined? Thanks for this @PhongPhan

Comment: @PhongPhan the updated answer actually doesnt work.  I couldnt get any of the values

Comment: After joining: `.joins(:status, application: :detail)`, what was the result? Empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163537/discussion-between-kingsley-simon-and-phong-phan).